# How do I use VLOOKUP with today's date or latest date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have a table with dates and their data, but the dates column don't have any formatting and is written as `yyyy-mm-dd`, e.g. 2016-08-29. It's aligned to the right. This table is generated from a Google Analytics script so I have no control over its formatting, i.e. I can't manually change the column into date format.

My question is how do I use `VLOOKUP` to look up today's date, then find value in column B?

This doesn't work as today() does not return the `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

```
=vlookup(today(),'datasheet'!A16:B1000,2,false)
```

This doesn't work either for some reason:

```
=vlookup(text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd"),'datasheet'!A16:B500,2,false)
```

This is what data table looks like:

[image: Data table]

How do I use `VLOOKUP` with today's date or latest date?

Comment: try changing `today()` to `TEXT(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")`

Comment: Tried that as well but didn't work either, returns N/A "didn't find 2016-08-29 in vlookup". That date is in the data table.

Comment: Can you add a column to the table? Or can you add a formula to a column of cells far enough to the right to not impact you usage?  The core issue is most likely the date looks like 42611.37 as far as the vlookup is concerned.

Comment: The data table is not editable in any way since it's generated by the GA script. Even if I edit it, the next time script is generated (daily) it'll just revert.

Comment: It looks like excel is treating the dates as true dates and not text.  Are you sure the first formula does not work?  I will bet that there is a time unit that is not being shown and there for Today() is not equal as the time will add a decimal to the date in column A.

Comment: Where are you trying a vlookup? Sounds like you get workbook A with tab Data, and the next time you are back at A>Data.  If so, the vlookup is supposed to be in workbook B and pull data from Workbook A .

Comment: Create a column and write this formula in the first Row **=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))** and see if it gives you the real date and copy it down if you have a date result copy this column and paste special value on a new place and use Vlookup on it

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a link to the file or a section of it shown so we can examine it

Answer (score 0):

You just have to reverse things around a bit in the logic.

Usually your formula would work fine if you could format the date column correctly, but if the date column is pulled through in a text format from another program automatically sometimes you don't have this option.  So what you can do is change the criteria you're matching it up with.  Instead of the lookup value being a date formatted date, you'll need to make the lookup value a text format date.

The below formula works for me using the sample set in the screenshot below.

`=VLOOKUP( TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd"),A:C,2,FALSE)`

Using the below sample set (every value is formatted as text) this gives me the value of `0.010297839`

Alternatively I would recommend using INDEX MATCH for this  as it's known to be a bit more reliable than `vlookup` or `hlookup`:

`=INDEX(A:C,MATCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd"),A:A,0), 2)`

This gives me the same result of `0.010297839`

[image]

**Troubleshooting:**
If the formula still doesn't work try a few more things:

- Try using the formula in the same sheet to test it's linked properly.  If you're using the formula from a different sheet or workbook, that could be throwing it out.
- Double check you actually have today's date in the data range.
- Use `A:B` in your formula rather than `A16:B500` to ensure no rows are excluded.
- As I say, the above formula's work for me, so if they're not working for you then there may be something else throwing it out that we don't know about.